# height 600px DIV displays as 480 pixels

Tags: html

I'm going crazy trying to figure out why a html div I specify ala

```
<div style="height: 600px; width: 600px; border: 1px solid black;"></div>
```

displays (in both Firefox and IE10, the only 2 browsers I have) as a
480x480 pixel square, not the 600x600 one I expected.  This is in a
simple html page without any CSS, tables, etc.  Changing the 600px to
800px gives a 640x640 pixel square, i.e. the displayed square is
always 80% of the size I've requested.  I've checked that my measured
sizes are correct by displaying a 600x600 PNG image in the browsers.

There's got to be something wrong in my understanding here, but I can't figure out what that is.

A test example is at http://bigsurtrailmap.net/HIKES/TRAILMAP/test2.divsize.html

Comment: It is 602px inclusive of the 1px border.. http://i.stack.imgur.com/PbkuN.png

Comment: Its 602 px on my machine as well. I took a screen shot and measured it in a graphic program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your browser presents the page in original size (to reset press [ctrl]+[0] (in most browsers)).

Comment: Thanks that worked - it now displays at 600 pixels.  Will now go looking through my installed plugins to see if one of them is responsible.  I've been writing webpages based upon what I'm seeing in this browser, so now must revisit some of that work!